# How to call the stored procedure in Snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to call the procedure created in main account from a reader account

I have couple of tables shared between them:

1. Employee
2. Procedure

`Procedure` table contains procedure names (to be called in main account) and id.

Calling the procedure as below but unable to do so

```
set var1 = (select procedure_name from procedure_calls);
call $var1;
```

Please let me know is it possible to call the way I am calling ?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to call the procedure created in main account from a reader
> account

Currently, you can't do this from a reader account. A reader account can run select queries on the tables and secure views its parent account shares to it, and that's all it can do. It can't run other statement types including CALL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the string with the stored procedure name in a literal `identifier()`:

```sql
set sp = 'Load_Employee';

call identifier($sp)()
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html

Answer (score 0):

Example - I have a stored procedure

```
    copy_into_temp_table(table_name VARCHAR)
```

It can be called via the below statement

```
 CALL copy_into_temp_table(EMP_TBL);
```